# Break of FOR loop after switch - C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, break

```
int realizar_reparaciones(int naves_a_reparar, int repuestos_laser, int repuestos_escudos, int repuestos_compensadores){
int caracter_valido = 0;
char reparacion_necesaria;
int naves_con_alambre = 0;
int contador_laser = 0;
int contador_escudo = 0;
printf ("A continuación deberá ingresar uno de los siguientes valores por nave: L (Generador Láser) o E (Generador de escudo deflector)\n");
for (int i = 1; i <= naves_a_reparar; i = i + 1){
    while (caracter_valido == 0){
        printf ("Ingrese la reparación que hay que realizarle a la nave %d: ", i);
        scanf (" %c", &reparacion_necesaria);
        switch (reparacion_necesaria){
            case 'L': 
                if (repuestos_laser == 0){
                    naves_con_alambre = naves_con_alambre + 1;
                } else {
                    repuestos_laser = repuestos_laser - 1;
                    contador_laser = contador_laser + 1;
                }
                caracter_valido = 1;
            break;
            case 'E': 
                if (repuestos_escudos == 0){
                    naves_con_alambre = naves_con_alambre + 1;
                } else {
                    repuestos_escudos = repuestos_escudos - 1;
                    contador_escudo = contador_escudo + 1;
                }
                caracter_valido = 1;
            break;
            default: 
                printf ("Ingrese unicamente alguno de los caracteres previamente mencionados\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
printf ("Se utilizaron %d generadores láser\n", contador_laser);
printf ("Se utilizaron %d generadores de escudos deflectores\n", contador_escudo);
printf ("Se utilizaron %d compensadores de aceleracion\n", contador_compensador);
return naves_con_alambre;
```

I have this function in C. i can only get the FOR to run once even if "naves_a_reparar" is 30 or any high number. After that, it goes out of the FOR loop and function ends. Why is this happening?

Comment: Debug it!. At a guess `caracter_valido` is not 0 anymore...

Comment: I think you dont need `break` after `default` case

Comment: @3stud1ant3 it's good practice though! if somebody adds a case after it would fall through

Comment: @John3136 That was it. So silly of me. I had to rewrite the code because i didn't save and i messed up. I wanted to solve this quickly. Thank you

Comment: @starmole thanks for your suggestion, but I have a question that wont it be bad practise if someone defines a case after `default` since it is meant to be the last case

Comment: @3stud1ant3: default does not have to be the last case! there can be crazy switch statements that handle a couple of case and break, then default with fall through. Not code anybody should write! But I have fixed bugs like that in production before. No break after default, and somebody just adds another case after default... so now i religiously put a break after default.